# With defernumbers, right biblatex' numeric labels even with skipbib, but wrong in case of citation \AtEndDocument

Tags: biblatex, numbering, biber

**Context:** `biblatex 2.9a` and `biber 1.9`.

Thanks to `defernumbers`, `biblatex`' numeric labels are right even with entries skipped from the bibliography (`options={skipbib}`), as shown by the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{skipbib-aaaa,
  title={Aaaa (skipped from bibliography)},
  options={skipbib}
}
@misc{bbbb,
  title = {Bbbb}
}
@misc{cccc,
  title={Cccc (manually added at end of document)}
}
@misc{dddd,
  title={Dddd (automatically added at end of document)}
}
\end{filecontents}
%
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers]{biblatex}%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
\begin{document}
\citetitle{skipbib-aaaa} and \citetitle{bbbb}
\printbibliography
\citetitle{cccc}%
% \AtEndDocument{and \citetitle{dddd}}
\end{document}
```

which gives (ascii art):

```
   Aaaa (skipped from bibliography) and Bbbb

References
[1] Bbbb.
[2] Cccc (manually added at end of document).

   Cccc (manually added at end of document)
```

But, as soon as a citation is added `\AtEndDocument` (by commenting out the penultimate line), the numeric labels get wrong (ascii art):

```
   Aaaa (skipped from bibliography) and Bbbb

References
[2] Bbbb.
[3] Cccc (manually added at end of document).
[4] Dddd (automatically added at end of document).

   Cccc (manually added at end of document)
   and Dddd (automatically added at end of document)
```

**Notes:**

- With `bibtex` as backend, no problem.
- With `biblatex 3.0` and `biber 2.0`, it's worse: with a citation added `\AtEndDocument`, all the numeric labels are `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

biblatex is doing a lot of (clean-up and other) work in the "end document" hook. You should make sure that your cite command is seen earlier. So either move your `\AtEndDocument` before `\usepackage{biblatex}`, or prepend the code to the hook:

```
\citetitle{cccc}%
\makeatletter\preto\@enddocumenthook{and \citetitle{dddd}}\makeatother
```

(I don't know if one the patch packages offers an "\PreToAtEndDocument" command).